# Need help caching json_decode(file_get_contents('api')) on wordpress website

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve data from coinmarketcap's api and store the data to cache file. If the cache file is older than 10 minutes, retrieve new data and store to cache file. I have been able to get everything to work, except for caching the data. The cache file is never created in the plugin directory. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code :

```
function Tickers($data){
    foreach($data as $item){
    echo "<a href=/currencies/" .$item->symbol. '/' . $item->name. ">$item->symbol</a>";    
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<span>$' . $item->price_usd . '</span>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
function getdata(){
$time = 600; //seconds
$cache_file = 'wp-content/plugins/cryptocurrency_tickers/cache.txt';
if(file_exists($cache_file)){
if(time() - filemtime($cache_file) > $time) {    
// too old , re-fetch
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=20'));
    file_put_contents(cache_file,json_encode($data));
}
    else{
        //data is current
    }
}else {
    // create cache 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=20'));
    file_put_contents(cache_file, json_encode($data));  
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache_file));
Tickers($data);
}
```

Comment: Does WP have permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: I checked the plugin directory owner permissions, and it appears that the plugin directory is writable.

Comment: Writable for you, or for the user under which WP runs?

Comment: I think it's just writable for the user under which WP runs, which would be a problem, right ?

Comment: Nope, this looks alright, it's the WP user that needs to write.

Comment: Managed to get it to work. Needed $cache_file = WP_CONTENT_DIR . 'cache.txt';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code again, missing '$' in front of 'cache_file' on file_put_contents

```
file_put_contents(cache_file,json_encode($data));
```

should be

```
file_put_contents($cache_file,json_encode($data));
```

Also when you get the json data from the API first you decode, then encode, why you didn't save the data directly from the API, it's already json encoded.

Better version of your code:

```
function Tickers($data){

    foreach($data as $item){
        echo "<a href=/currencies/" .$item->symbol. '/' . $item->name. ">$item->symbol</a>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<span>$' . $item->price_usd . '</span>';
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

function getdata(){

    $time       = 600; //seconds
    $cache_file = '/path/to/cache.txt';

    if(file_exists($cache_file)){

        if(time() - filemtime($cache_file) > $time) {
            // too old , re-fetch
            $data = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=20');

            file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);

        } else{
            //data is current
        }
    } else {
        // create cache
        $data = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=20');

        file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);
    }

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache_file));

    Tickers($data);
}

getdata();
```

Also make sure the plugin directory is writable by your web server user.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the missing $. I checked the plugin directory owner permissions, and it appears that the plugin directory is writable. The cache file is still not being created for some reason.

Comment: Try to add the full path to the cache file, instead of 'wp-content/plugins/cryptocurrency_tickers/cache.txt' like '/var/www/yousite.com/wp-content/plugins/cryptocurrency_tickers/cache.txt'. Also you can enable the error log and display errors to see if some error when trying to create the file.

Comment: I tried that , going to enable the error log next and see if I can find any errors related. I need some sleep though as this is driving me crazy. I'll continue later. Thanks for the continued help and support.

Comment: Managed to get it to work. Needed $cache_file = WP_CONTENT_DIR . 'cache.txt'; Thanks again for all the help!